# pyqt qtextedit move cursor

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4

I am using Qtextedit with a search button. here is the code.

```
 format = QTextCharFormat()
 format.setBackground(QBrush(QColor("Gray")))
 regex = QRegExp(pattern)
 if (self.ui_log.checkBox_case.isChecked()==False):
    regex.setCaseSensitivity(False)
 pos = 0
 index = regex.indexIn(self.ui_log.log_textEdit.toPlainText(), pos)
 while (index != -1):
     cursor.setPosition(index)
     cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.EndOfWord, 1)
     cursor.mergeCharFormat(format)
      pos = index + regex.matchedLength()
      self.ui_log.log_textEdit.moveCursor(??????)
      index = regex.indexIn(self.ui_log.log_textEdit.toPlainText(), pos)
```

Qtextedit have a scrollbar as the input file i am providing in qtextedit is large..

The searched text is high lighted, how can i move to searched text by providing index of word ?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of moving the existing cursor, set a new one:

```
self.ui_log.log_textEdit.setTextCursor(cursor);
```